# How to move a windows machine properly from RAID 1 to raid 10?

Tags: windows-7, raid, raid-1, raid-10

## Goal

I would like to add two more hard drives to my current RAID 1 setup and create a RAID 0 setup on top of the two RAID 1 setups (which I believe is referred to as "RAID 10").

## Components Involved

- Intel P68 Chipset Motherboard
- 4 SATA ports that can be configured for Raid
- An intel SSD cache that sits in front of the RAID, and a 64 GB SSD configured in that manner
- Two 1TB HDDs configured in RAID 1
- OS: Windows 7 Professional

## Resources Consulted so far

- I found a [great resource on LinuxQuestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/convert-raid-1-system-into-raid-1-0-a-557471/) for a good "best practices" process for Linux machines, but I'd like to develop a similar process that I know works on Windows Machines.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Windows 7 does not support a "software" RAID 1+0 configuration. You would first need to find out if your motherboard supports "hardware" RAID 1+0 configurations. If it does, then I'd suggest:

- Backing up your OS and data using the Windows backup and recovery tools
- Create the "hardware" RAID 1+0 configuration in your BIOS.
- Create a WindowsPE boot CD with the necessary RAID drivers loaded onto the disk
- Reinstall a base image of Windows, and use the recovery tools to restore the image you made of your OS

Below are some links I used as a reference:

**Windows 7 Pro x64 RAID 1 System Image --> Restore to RAID 5**

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproinstall/thread/7a7529ef-f8ac-4c0b-bdd5-d967acee0b9f/

**Deploy a System Recovery Image**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744280(v=ws.10).aspx

Hope this information helps!